# SCNText rendering without curves, not font-like

Tags: ios, scenekit, scntext

When I run this SceneKit code:

```
let txt = SCNText(string: "Hello", extrusionDepth: 0.2)
let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: txt)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)
```

I get very angular text:

[image: Poorly rendered text]

It seems to do this regardless of font and it behaves the same way on a device as in the simulator.

Here's the code in context:

```
    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 10, y: 0, z: 75)

    // create and add a light to the scene
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    let txt = SCNText(string: "Hello", extrusionDepth: 0.2)

    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: txt)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)



    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    // set the scene to the view
    scnView.scene = scene
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SCNText` subdivides the 2D Bézier path for your text just like Core Graphics would do if you were drawing it. You can always use the `flatness` property to make it smoother, but you won't get "sub-pixel smoothness".

To solve this issue you can use a bigger font size, so that the underlying Bézier path is bigger and more vertices are generated when discretization occurs.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was using big font as @mnuages was suggested then using scale on the text node with

```
     animatedTextNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
```

to get what size I wanted.

In that case when you animate text and when it comes closer to the camera it looks smooth.